# process execution problem in linux

Tags: java, linux

I wanted to open a file in notepad(using   JAVA) by...

proc.exec("notepad "+curDir+"\auto_saved.txt");

where...

```
 String curDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
 curDir=curDir+"/txt-files";                
 Runtime proc = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

this works properly in WIN7 but says      'home..........\auto_saved.txt'  PATH     not found. in LINUX.
but if I save  a file to  (curDir+"\auto_saved.txt");..it creates a file and saves  it in LINUX.

So, how to open a file in /home/user/some-folder/...??

Comment: There is no **notepad** app on linux.

Comment: The string literal `"\auto_saved.txt"` is not valid Java and will cause a compile error.  It'd have to be `"\\auto_saved.txt"`.  Are you sure that's your real code?

Comment: no error..n working fine in WIN7...for ubuntu  its  "/auto_saved.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no notepad editor in Linux.  Many linux distributions have a text editor called "nano", in /usr/bin/nano;  Ubuntu/Debian puts a text editor in /etc/alternatives/editor ; you could also also check env{EDITOR}, which sometimes contains a user set pathname to a text editor, and override your choice of editor if present to allow for user customization.
2. You might want to use the full path to the executable when you call exec, in case it is not on the path.

Comment: I tried this..String pathWIN7=curDir+"/auto_saved.txt"; shows.."C:/users/abhishek/txt-files/auto_saved.txt 
String pathLINUX="txt-files/auto_saved.txt";shows.."txtfiles/auto_saved.txt"           //means no need to give "home/user/.." path                                                                                                                                      //but i saved file to "home/user/txt-files/auto_saved.txt"
proc.exec("notepad "+pathWIN7);//if os.name is windows 7
proc.exec("notepad "+pathLINUX);//if os.name is Ubuntu
this is working.........bt..could not understand why ..

Comment: there is a notepad as part of WINE project for Ubuntu.  However, it is not part of a standard Ubuntu install.

Comment: You might check to see if the process returns to fast.  There is a program that runs briefly, when I enter "notepad a.txt" to a shell prompt, "The program 'notepad' can be found in the following packages:
 * wine1.2
 * wine1.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>"  I wonder if this will also appear if you try to call up notepad from java within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting the `\` in `"\auto_saved.txt"` to be a directory separator, but in Linux it isn't, it's just an ordinary character that can be part of a filename.  Use `File.pathSeparator` (a static field in `java.io.File`) instead; it'll be `/` on Linux/Unix and `\` on Windows.

Comment: \ is generally an escape character in Linux/Unix. It could be used in a filename but it would have to be double escaped - `touch \\file\\ ` - creates a file named \file\.

Comment: It's also an escape character in Java, and `\a` isn't a valid escape sequence, so `"\auto_saved.txt"` actually won't compile.